# Find $\max, \min, \inf, \sup$

Tags: real-analysis

Find the $\max, \min, \sup, \inf$ if they exist of $B=\frac{n}{2n+1}$ such that $n$ is a natural number`

I know that the $\min B=0=\inf B$, but I'm struggling to understand what the $\sup B$ and $\max B$ would be.

Comment: Do you include $0$ in the natural numbers?

Comment: @graydad: He must include $n=0$, since the min and inf are zero.

Answer (score 3):

The $B$'s are increasing, and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}B=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2n+1}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2+\frac 1n}$$
$$=\frac 12$$

$B$ can never be $1/2$, so there is no max, and the sup is $1/2$.

(That last expression for $B$ shows that it is increasing. Trying to solve $B=\frac 12$ shows there is no solution, though $B$ strictly increasing also shows there is no max.)

Answer (score 2):

This sequence is always increasing, that is, we always have $B_{n+1}>B_n$ (check it!), so there is no maximum. (Given any $B_n$, there is always a greater element, namely, $B_{n+1}$).

Since the sequence is increasing, the supremum is its limit. You can find it by writing $B_n=n/\left(2n+1\right) = 1/\left(2+n^{-1}\right)$, and then letting $n\to\infty$.